# how to integrate umbraco with mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I am currently developing an eCommerce application with MVC4 on IIS7.5.

I would like to integrate in the application a CMS. From researching the numerous CMS's out there,I have decided that the best for my needs is Umbraco. I would like to use this CMS for primarily managing landing pages on the site.

I have very little experience with Umbraco so need some help. What is best way to integrate in Umbraco in to an MVC4 application? Are tutorials or similar out there that could assist me with this?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Which approach did you end up going with?

Answer (score 0):

MVC support in Umbraco is improving all the time, and seems to be the focus of the ongoing project work (according to the recent level two training course I went on).  At the moment you can integrate MVC and Umbraco using the [MVC Bridge](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/mvcbridge) Umbraco add-on or roll your own integration.

Using MVC Bridge you can render out an MVC view by choosing to add an Umbraco macro to a template as "MVCRenderAction" type, and setting the appropriate "Action" and "Controller" attributes.

I think that MVCBridge is a stopgap - and am willing to wait for full support, but your timescales may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I usually hook up MVC applications to Umbraco to render partials and controls. Mainly MVC 2 to keep the syntax the same since I still prefer webforms, but any MVC version will do.

The way to go is Dependency Injection and IoC. This means you will run your MVC application as an application inside the Umbraco site.

To connect the applications you need a Unity Container, I prefer Microsoft Unity.

I could write a 10 pages long article about this but some of the OP's at SO doesn't like that so I will link to a blog-post instead (not my blog), it contains most of the stuff you need.

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/05/07/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-app-using-unity-2-0.aspx