# Path problems with running a sub application (umbraco) inside my MVC4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, umbraco

I have this MVC4 web application, I run it locally at mySite.local/. I created an application in IIS 7, mapping to mySite.local/corporateSite/. I point that application to an Umbraco (CMS) installation I have locally.

This works pretty well.

I have these UI images and .css files that were in my corporate site and were linked-to by absolute urls (Examples: /css/myCss.css, /media/ui/myFunLogo.png, etc.).

Now this "/" root has changed, if I want my css and images to work, I have to use /corporateSite/cssmyCss.css... this is logical.

How can I change my configuration or sites setup or code so that I don't have to write that whenever I'm linking to a file like that. Should I use rewrite rules to prepend the application url?

How to people integrate these elements normally ? I know a lot go through subdomains, but this would not be ideal for us at the moment.

Thanks for the help!

(I think my question is related to this one [how to integrate umbraco with mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653133/how-to-integrate-umbraco-with-mvc4) but in some different aspects. And the answers are not good for me.)

Answer (score 1):

In umbracoSettings.config, there is a setting for "ResolveUrlsFromTextString".

Setting it to *true* should tell Umbraco to add the virtual directory name to links and images.

Comment: Actually I spoke too fast, this doesn't adjust the urls, because they are "hardcoded" in my UI. Example : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/myCss.css" media="all" />. The /corporateSite portion does not get prepended...

Comment: Do you have runat="server" on your head element? If so stick a tilde before /css. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424114/slash-vs-tilde-slash-in-style-sheet-path-in-asp-net